# DVD to iMovie converter for Mac 10.4.11

Tags: macbook-pro, imovie, dvd, movie

First of all, is there such a thing? All I want to do is be able to import film clips from DVDs into iMovie so I can make groovy youtube videos. Any suggestions for a Mac 10.4.11 user?

Answer (score 8):

I use [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/). It's free and open, and works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

You have so many choices on OS X. Here it goes, take a look at [this tutorial link](http://www.moviesmac.com/tutorial/dvd-imovie-mac.html) for your question answered step by step.

Other excellent (and easy!) software to use are:

-[iRip it from The Little App Factory](http://thelittleappfactory.com/ripit/)

-[Permute from Fuel Collective](http://fuelcollective.com/permute)

-[iFlicks from Jendrick Bertram](http://www.iflicksapp.com/)
I translated the last one in French for...French users ;)

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

MacTheRipper also does a decent job of this, although the author makes it deliberately hard to get hold of. You need to join the forums at http://www.ripdifferent.com/forum to get download instructions.

Answer (score -1):

[Rip the DVD](http://www.softzz.com/how-to/rip-dvd-to-mp4-mpeg-4-for-osx-lion.html) to an iMovie supported video format such as mov or mp4.

Comment: The question refers to OSX 10.4, the tool here requires Lion :-(

Comment: This question specifically asks for a solution in OS X Tiger.